# How do I send out an email to multiple people with the same email address?

Tags: marketing-cloud

So, I need to be able to send out an email that could include an individual with different purchases. I set-up a SubscriberKey that is unique and links to the Subscriber Key and not the email address.

That was my understanding of how I can send an email multiple times to the same email address. Below is my data extension set-up:

[image]

I've added test data to the DE with my personal and work email twice with each one having a unique SubscriberKey. I should receive 4 emails, 2 to each email address. However, I only receive 1 email for each email address.

I know this has to be something simple that I'm overlooking. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you send your emails? If from Journey Builder, then those won’t be deduplicated... if from Email Studio, there is an option in the flow to turn on/off deduplication by email address

Comment: In Journey Builder that runs daily. Each day a new set of contacts are uploaded and on some days a user might show up twice but each time the contact has a unique Subscriber_Key which is set to be the Primary Key.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the below scenario,
"A bank want to send a monthly balance statement to all its customers. But, **imagine all 4 members in a family share a COMMON email address!** [see example below] Where in 2 families with both having 4 members, but have a common email address per Family."
[image]

> So you can leverage the concept called **COMPOSITE KEY** [in simple combination of Primary Keys]!

[image]

So with this approach, by disabling the De-duplicate option as below,
[image]

I was successfully able to get 4 emails for each email-address! In practical all 4 emails with have separate Balance and FirstName as below.
[image]